# Can't rescue the third hostage

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I tried playing AC 3 and got to the part where I'm freeing the hostages for the first time.

What happens is I get outside of the fort wall. As soon as I sneak onto the boat and try to free the hostage near the edge of the ship, I get caught. If I assassinate the guard first, I get caught still in plain site.

Is there more than one option?

I can free the other two, the ones within the fort, not get caught, AND EVEN assassinate the guards without getting caught either, if I take a few tries. But I seem perplexed at the fact that I don't see a lot to sneak around on the boat.

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew which mission you're talking about. Right now, all I can think about is Haytham rescuing native hostages from a British fort; and there are no boats in that mission.

Comment: I think Haythem is a templar right? I thought there was a Pirate boat next to the dock, where the fort is. And yes, it's from a British fort, near the beginning of the game, but the fort is in the US. If it's not a sailboat, then what is it? It looks like a pirate ship to me.

Comment: @Nolonar there _is_ a boat in that sequence, it is docked near the stone walls

Comment: I'm a bit confused right now; is it the sequence, where you are first introduced to the concept of "Human Shield"?

Comment: It's an optional objective in Sequence 7 where you go through the warzone on a timer.

Comment: what are sequences in a video game?

Comment: I know what mission he's talking about, Sequence 2, Mission 5. However I won't edit this into the question until he's confirmed this.

Comment: So I assassinate the captain that's looking for me. Then I assassinate the guard who is guarding the hostage. Then I free the hostage?

Answer (score 2):

I did this mission last night. After freeing the first two sets of of hostages (easy), you need to kill the captain on the docks (hide behind some of the stacks of crates on the docks and get him as he comes around the corner - whistle if you're impatient).

Once he's out of the way, you can climb on the boat. There is one more guard right by the hostage and you should be able to take him out the easily.